# ERROR: could not find function "forceNetworkOutput" while trying to deploy app on shiny.io

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

I am trying to build a shiny app which makes use of the `networkD3` package in R to create visualizations of correlated terms for each President. The code is as follows.

```
    #### Load necessary packages and data ####
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(widyr)
if(!require("networkD3"))install.packages("networkD3")
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

inaug <- read.csv("inaug_speeches.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
important_words <- inaug %>%
  unnest_tokens(word,text) %>%
  filter(str_detect(word,"^[a-z]+$")) %>%
  group_by(Name,word)%>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  bind_tf_idf(word,Name,n) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(desc(tf_idf)) %>%
  top_n(10)

plotTheme <- function(base_size = 12) {
  theme(
    text = element_text( color = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10,colour = "black",hjust=0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(face="italic"),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_line("grey80", size = 0.1),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80", color = "white"),
    strip.text = element_text(size=8),
    axis.title = element_text(size=5),
    axis.text = element_text(size=5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(hjust=1),
    axis.title.y = element_text(hjust=1),
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=-1,angle=90,size=10))
}


# create a vector of names
persons <- inaug %>% select(Name) %>% unique()

## for the progress bar
compute_data <- function(updateProgress = NULL) {
  # Create 0-row data frame which will be used to store data
  dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

  for (i in 1:10) {
    Sys.sleep(0.25)

    # Compute new row of data
    new_row <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1))

    # If we were passed a progress update function, call it
    if (is.function(updateProgress)) {
      text <- paste0("x:", round(new_row$x, 2), " y:", round(new_row$y, 2))
      updateProgress(detail = text)
    }

    # Add the new row of data
    dat <- rbind(dat, new_row)
  }

  dat
}

plot_network <- function(data,person){

  words_to_check <- important_words %>% filter(Name==person) %>% select(word)


  data_new_cor <- data %>%
    unnest_tokens(word,text) %>%
    filter(!word %in% stop_words$word)%>%
    pairwise_cor(word,X) %>%
    filter(item1 %in% words_to_check$word) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    filter(correlation>0.7)

  item1 <- data_new_cor$item1
  item2 <- data_new_cor$item2
  n <- data_new_cor$correlation

  nodeFactors <- factor(sort(unique(c(item1, item2))))
  nodes <- data.frame(name = nodeFactors, group = 1)

  item1 <- match(item1, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1
  item2 <- match(item2, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1
  links <- data.frame(item1, item2, n)

  forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'item1', 
               Target = 'item2', Value = 'n', NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group',fontSize = 25,
               colourScale = JS('force.alpha(1); force.restart(); d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);'),
               opacity = 0.85, zoom = TRUE, opacityNoHover = 0.1,
               linkWidth = networkD3::JS("function(d) { return d.correlation/5; }"))

}


#### Server ####
server <- function(input, output) {



  output$force <- renderForceNetwork({

    # Create a Progress object
    progress <- shiny::Progress$new()
    progress$set(message = "Crunching the numbers...", value = 0)
    # Close the progress when this reactive exits (even if there's an error)
    on.exit(progress$close())

    # Create a callback function to update progress.
    # Each time this is called:
    # - If `value` is NULL, it will move the progress bar 1/5 of the remaining
    #   distance. If non-NULL, it will set the progress to that value.
    # - It also accepts optional detail text.
    updateProgress <- function(value = NULL, detail = NULL) {
      if (is.null(value)) {
        value <- progress$getValue()
        value <- value + (progress$getMax() - value) / 5
      }
      progress$set(value = value, detail = detail)
    }

    # Compute the new data, and pass in the updateProgress function so
    # that it can update the progress indicator.
    compute_data(updateProgress)


    plot_network(inaug,input$var)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    important_words %>%
      filter(Name==input$var) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=reorder(word,tf_idf),y=tf_idf))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      labs(title="Top Terms By TF-IDF Value",x="Word",y="TF-IDF Value")+plotTheme()




  })

}

#### UI ####

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Visualization of Top correlated Terms and top 10 TF IDF values "),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$style("#force{height:100vh !important;}")),
      tags$head(tags$style("#plot{height:50vh !important;}")),

      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "President's Name",
                  choices = dput(persons$Name),
                  selected = "George Washington"),
      plotOutput("plot")


    ),
    mainPanel(


       forceNetworkOutput("force"),
       style = "border: 1px solid black;"

      )
    )
  )
)

#### Run ####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I looked up on this issue on Stackoverflow with other examples pertaining to Shiny app not running on the Shiny.io platform and there seemed to be an issue regarding date formats . The dataset used for this project can be found at https://github.com/adhok/rvest-project . Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [shinyapps.io User Manual](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud) says that you "should not have an explicit `install.packages()` call within your ui.R or server.R files", so maybe change this

`if(!require("networkD3"))install.packages("networkD3")`

to this

`library(networkD3)`

Comment: I had to modify some of the code so that the server doesn't time out, but it works conceptually here: https://cjyetman.shinyapps.io/test2/